# Aborted (core dumped) in C in the last row

Tags: c

I am using cygwin, I am getting after the output in the last raw aborted (dumped core) I uploaded an image of the output this is my code in the code. I have **Array.h**, **Array.c**, **Table.c**, **Table.h** and **main.c**.

Code: table header file **Table.h**:

```
#ifndef EX4_TABLE_H
#define EX4_TABLE_H
#include "Array.h"

typedef struct Table *TableP;
TableP TableCreate();
void TableDestroy(TableP p);
char* TableRowName(TableP p, int i);
char* TableColumnName(TableP p, int i);
int TableNumColumns(TableP p);
int TableNumRows(TableP p);
Element TableGet(TableP p, int i, int j);
void TableSet(TableP p, int i, int j, Element val);
void TableAddRow(TableP p, char *name);
void TableAddColumn(TableP p, char *name, Element (*cpy)(Element), void(*fre)(Element));

#endif
```

Table C file  **Table.c**:

```
#include "Table.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Table {
    Array *arr;
    int numOfCul;
    char **name_cul;
    int rowSize;
    char **name_row;
};

TableP TableCreate() {
    TableP p = (TableP)malloc(sizeof(struct Table));
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(struct Table));
        exit(0);
    }
    p->name_cul = NULL;
    p->name_row = NULL;
    p->arr = NULL;
    p->numOfCul = 0;
    p->rowSize = 0;
    return p;
}

void TableDestroy(TableP p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p->numOfCul; i++) {
        ArrayDestroy(p->arr[i]);
        free(p->name_cul[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < p->rowSize; j++) {
            free(p->name_row[j]);
        }
    }
    free(p);
}

void TableAddRow(TableP p, char *name) {
    p->rowSize = p->rowSize + 1;
    p->name_row = (char **)realloc(p->name_row, sizeof(char*) * p->rowSize);
    p->name_row[p->rowSize - 1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    strcpy(p->name_row[p->rowSize-1], name);
    for (int i = 0; i < p->numOfCul; i++) {
        ArrayResize(p->arr[i], p->rowSize);
    }
}

void TableAddColumn(TableP p, char *name, Element (*cpy)(Element), void(*fre)(Element)) {
    p->numOfCul = p->numOfCul + 1;
    p->name_cul = (char **)realloc(p->name_cul, sizeof(char*) * p->numOfCul);
    p->name_cul[p->numOfCul - 1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    strcpy(p->name_cul[p->numOfCul - 1], name);
    p->arr = (Array *)realloc(p->arr, sizeof(Array));
    p->arr[p->numOfCul - 1] = ArrayCreate(p->rowSize, cpy, free);
}

void TableSet(TableP p, int i, int j, Element val) {
    if (i > p->numOfCul || j > p->rowSize) {
        printf("number not in range \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    ArraySet(p->arr[i], j, val);
}

Element TableGet(TableP p, int i, int j) {
    if (i > p->numOfCul || j > p->rowSize) {
        printf("number not in range \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return ArrayGet(p->arr[i], j);
}

int TableNumRows(TableP p) {
    return p->rowSize;
}

int TableNumColumns(TableP p) {
    return p->numOfCul;
}

char *TableRowName(TableP p, int i) {
    if (p->rowSize < i) {
        printf("num row is wrong\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p->name_row[i];
}

char *TableColumnName(TableP p, int i) {
    if (p->rowSize < i) {
        printf("num row is wrong\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p->name_cul[i];
}
```

File **Array.h**:

```
#ifndef EX4_ARRAY_H
#define EX4_ARRAY_H

typedef void *Element;
typedef struct Array *Array;

/*
 * Array constructor, expects to get the size of the array, a copy function for the type of elements to be kept
 * and a free function. Array is initialized with NULL values
 */
Array ArrayCreate(unsigned int n, Element (*cpy)(Element), void(*fre)(Element));
/*
 * Array destractor
 */
void ArrayDestroy(Array a);
/*
 * Keeps a copy of element e in index i. Will print an error message and terminate the program if i is out of range.
 * The element that was kept in index i (if there is any) will be deleted
 */
void ArraySet(Array a, unsigned int i, Element e);
/*
 * Returns the element in index i (NULL if there is no element stored). Will print an error message and terminate the
 * program if i is out of range.
 */
Element ArrayGet(Array a, unsigned int i);
/*
 * Returns the size of the array
 */
unsigned int ArraySize(Array a);
/*
 * Changes the size of the array. If the new size if hiigher than current size then empty cells will be added.
 * If the new size is smaller, then the items at the end of the array will be deleted.
 * newn can be 0 (resulting with an empty array).
 */
void ArrayResize(Array a, unsigned int newn);

#endif
```

File **Array.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Array.h"

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
struct Array {
    Element *elements;
    unsigned int num_elements;
    Element (*cpy)(Element);
    void (*fre)(Element);
};

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
Array ArrayCreate(unsigned int n, Element (*cpy)(Element), void(*fre)(Element)) {
    Array array = (Array)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Array));
    if (!array) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(struct Array));
        exit(-1);
    }
    array->num_elements = n;
    array->elements = (Element)calloc(array->num_elements, sizeof(Element));
    if (!array->elements) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(Element)*array->num_elements);
        exit(-1);
    }
    array->cpy = cpy;
    array->fre = fre;

    return array;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
void ArrayDestroy(Array a) {
    ArrayResize(a, 0);
    free(a->elements);
    free(a);
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
void ArraySet(Array a, unsigned int i, Element e) {
    if (i >= a->num_elements) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError, %s: tried to set an element in index %u, array size is %u. Aborting\n\n", __FUNCTION__, i, a->num_elements);
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (a->elements[i])
        a->fre(a->elements[i]);
    a->elements[i] = a->cpy(e);
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
Element ArrayGet(Array a, unsigned int i) {
    if (i >= a->num_elements) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError, %s: tried to get an element from index %u, array size is %u. Aborting\n\n", __FUNCTION__, i, a->num_elements);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return a->elements[i];
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
unsigned int ArraySize(Array a) {
    return a->num_elements;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
void ArrayResize(Array a, unsigned int newn) {
    // If the new size is smaller than the older one then remove the extra elements
    if (newn < a->num_elements) {
        for (;a->num_elements > newn; a->num_elements--) {
            a->fre(a->elements[a->num_elements - 1]);
        }
    }
    // If the new size is 0 then free a->elements and leave
    if (newn == 0) {
        free(a->elements);
        a->elements = NULL;
        return;
    }
    a->elements = (Element)realloc(a->elements, sizeof(Element) * newn);
    if (!a->elements) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(Element)*newn);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // If the new size is larger than the old size - fill the newly added cells with NULL
    if (newn > a->num_elements) {
        for (; a->num_elements < newn; a->num_elements++)
            a->elements[a->num_elements] = NULL;
    }
}
```

File **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Table.h"

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
Element str_cpy(Element e) {
    char *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen((char*)e) + 1));
    if (!s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(char)*(strlen((char*)e)+1));
        exit(-1);
    }
    strcpy(s, (char*)e);
    return (Element)s;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
Element int_cpy(Element e) {
    int *i = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!i) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n%s/%u: failed to allocate %lu bytes. Aborting\n\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, sizeof(int));
        exit(-1);
    }
    *i = *((int *)e);
    return (Element)i;
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************/
int main() {
    TableP t = TableCreate();

    TableAddColumn(t, "Int1", int_cpy, free);
    TableAddColumn(t, "Char1", str_cpy, free);
    TableAddColumn(t, "Int2", int_cpy, free);
    TableAddColumn(t, "Char2", str_cpy, free);

    srand(42);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int i1 = 500 + i, i2 = i1 * i1;
        char str[32];
        sprintf(str, "r%d", i);
        TableAddRow(t, str);
        TableSet(t, 0, i, &i1);
        sprintf(str, "Hello_%d", i1);
        TableSet(t, 1, i, str);
        TableSet(t, 2, i, &i2);
        sprintf(str, "Bye_%d", i2);
        TableSet(t, 3, i, str);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TableNumColumns(t); i++) {
        printf("\t%s", TableColumnName(t, i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int r = 0; r < TableNumRows(t); r++) {
        printf("%s", TableRowName(t, r));
        for (int c = 0; c < TableNumColumns(t); c++) {
            if (c == 0 || c == 2)
                printf("\t%d", *(int *)(TableGet(t, c, r)));
            else
                printf("\t%s", (const char *)(TableGet(t, c, r)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    TableDestroy(t);

    return 0;
}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Run your code in a debugger. That core dump should give you a real insight as to where the problem is manifesting. Note that doesn't guarantee it is the problem *origin*, but it will still give some concrete ideas. Frankly, writing this much code without unit testing components in a debugger and address sanitizer is an open invitation to disaster.

Comment: I compiled it with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and noticed that you get a heap buffer overflow in `TableAddColumn`.

Comment: At a glance, I see you have a bug in `TableDestroy`, where you have the `j` loop nested inside the `i` loop, which means you will attempt to `free` `p->name_row[j]` multiple times, which will cause an error.

Comment: once you fix the bug above, note that both `p->name_row` and `p->name_cul` also need to be free'd before freeing the final `p`, lest you desire a leak.

Comment: thanks after fixing the bugs in TableDestroy it worked fine thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you test for `malloc` failures but not everywhere, nor do you check for `realloc` failures. You should write wrappers or macros for these functions that perform the test and exit gracefully upon failure. This would make the calling code more readable.
- in `TableDestroy`, the 2 `for` loops should not be nested. This causes multiple free for the same pointers.
- when setting column and row names, you should use `strdup()` instead of allocating a harcoded length of 8 and using `strcpy` without checking that the name fits.
- in `TableAddColumn` the array pointed to by `p->arr` is not resized to the new number of entries. You should have:

  ```
    p->arr = (Array *)realloc(p->arr, sizeof(Array) * p->numOfCul);
  ```
- the test in `TableSet` and `TableGet` is incorrect: you should use `>=` instead of `>`, report the error to `stderr` and exit with a non zero status:

  ```
    if (i >= p->numOfCul || j >= p->rowSize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table coordinates out of range: %d,%d\n", i, j);
        exit(1);
    }
  ```
- same problem in `TableRowName` and `TableColumnName`
- hiding pointers behind typedefs is confusing and error prone. Especially confusing is the typedef `typedef struct Array *Array;`